# React native IOS app web-services works on simulator but not real IOS device

Tags: ios, react-native

I have done with all the settings of my react native project and **trying to run on the IOS simulator, it's working fine**. **Means all the api working properly**.

So now **I have to share my .ipa file** to team members for testing, so creating  .ipa file I am using procedure defined on react native[Running On Device](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#building-your-app-for-production) documentation.

**For creating .ipa file using Xcode following below process:-**

1. In **Edit Scheme** option, change **Build Configuration** to **release**.
2. Clean Build Folder
3. Create Build.
4. Archive build.
5. After that exporting .ipa file using valid certificate.

**Solutions I have tried:-**

1. Checked with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40299837/4214266), because the **domain** I am using **to hit web service is not secured**.(It's http)
2. Enable Transport security flag.
3. Added main.jbundle **(created using command line)** to Copy Bundle Resource option in Build Phases.
4. While adding **Alert** in api call, getting below error **(check image)**
   [image]

**Still No luck.**

**Please let me know, what I am doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check api server live link is working or not. In my case, I am testing whole api's on local network (In LAN). But when trying with live url, I am also facing this issue.

So that time I made one mistake, that my url should contain **http://** but in actual it was **https://**.

> It's pointing to main.jsbundle file, that means it's having issue
>   related with your code.

So check it once.

Comment: Ok, Let me check it once.